# Parameters through url

Tags: magento2, url, forms, request

I'm trying go get parameters from my submitted form (my form is devided in two parts). When I submit my first form, my page go to the second part (on the right view). But I'm stuck here. I have that :

```
class Form extends Action
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;

    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
    {
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name');
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
```

How do I display $name on my view ? Here's my view, I tried :

```
<?php echo $name; ?>
<?php echo $this->name; ?>
```

None of these worked.

EDIT : in post method in my form, my url is like that :

```
http://dev.site.com/connexion/connexion/Form/name/nameofclient/code/00theCode00/
```

EDIT SOLUTION : 
This one didn't work :

```
$params = $block->getRequest()->getParams();
```

But this one did :

```
echo $block->getRequest()->getParam('name');
```

Thank you very much for your answer, it was helpful !

Comment: You can directly call inside phtml file like below,

$params = $block->getRequest()->getParams();

Comment: I tried this : <?php $params = $block->getRequest()->getParams();
var_dump($params);?> but it's not working either

Comment: @MorganTartreau do you got solution?

Comment: Yes, see "edit solution" in my first post

Answer (score 0):

**Write below code in Controller**

```
protected $_name;
protected $_resultPageFactory;


public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
{
    $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    $this->getVariable(); 
    $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
    return $resultPage;
}

public function getVariable()
{
   $this->_name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name'); 
   return $this->_name;
}
```

Call "getVariable" function in view page.

Note: view.phtml file will be  this block view file.

`$block->getVariable()`;

Comment: Thanks but it's not working, I have a complete white page. I need to had ($resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;) otherwise my page is empty, i don't know why (i'm new in magento)

Comment: are you in get request or post request?

Comment: try updated code

Comment: I'm in post, but my input value are in the url (i don't know why, that's strange...)

Comment: I have no error, but the name is not display

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class Form extends Action
{
    protected $_resultPageFactory;
    protected $_helper;
    public function __construct(
        Context $context, 
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        {{Your module package}}\{{Your module }}\Helper\Data $helper
    )
    {
        $this->_helper = $helper;
        $this->_resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


    public function execute()
    {
        $name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name');
        $this->_helper->setName($name);
        $resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
        return $resultPage;
    }
```

Create your `helper` file and set data in that `object`.

```
class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    protected $_setFormName;

    public function setName($formName)
    {
        $this->_setFormName = $formName;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->_setFormName;
    }

}
```

Now you can access Helper in your `PHTML` with this.

```
$_helper = $this->helper('{{Your module package}}\{{Your module }}\Helper\Data');
$_helper->getName();
```

Comment: Where do I put the helper file ? And what is it ? I read that it's some code I can use anywhere in my website, but i only need it to be in only one part of the site. Will there be any security issue with that ? Thx

Comment: Sorry, It was my mistake, I have updated my answer. You need to create new helper file. You can put this code:
`$_helper = $this->helper('{{Your module package}}\{{Your module }}\Helper\Data');
$_helper->getName();`

In your `PHTML` file.